# PublishOptions with include does not work on Debug Asp.net Core

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I'm using Asp.net Core version `1.0.0-preview2-003131` in VisualStudio 2015.

The strange part is , even though my `appsettings.json` is added in `publishOptions`, it is not generated during Debug. However, it will be generated in Release version.

I'm using Visual Studio to compile and debug, not command.

My Project.json:

```
"publishOptions": {
  "include": [
    "appsettings.json"
  ]
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Below is my BuildOptions in Project.json:

```
"buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
},
```

Even by adding `"debugType": "full"` does not help to resolve this

**UPDATE:**
Until today I'm no longer use VS 2015 anymore. Thank you for following up on this so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can try by adding `appsettings.Production.json` into this array of `publishOptions`.

Comment: Do you mean i should try to update to become this `"include":["appsettings.Production.json" ]` or do I need to rename my json file as well (e.g: rename the file to appsettings.Production.json)

Comment: No need to rename json file.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
 "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "appsettings.json",
      "appsettings.Production.json",
    ]
  },
```

This lists all the files and folders that will be included when you publish.

Comment: Try adding "appsettings*.json" and check.

Comment: Same, please take note that it works well on Release function. Only Debug does not work

Comment: In your Project.json, check the buildOption in that check the value of "debugType".

Comment: Take reference from here: https://www.intertech.com/Blog/cross-platform-asp-net-core-debugging-visual-studio-code/